# Displace Modifier on an object

Tags: uv, modifiers, displacement

i have to apply a dotted displacement map to a object that i created.
I tried to apply it but it breaks my mesh. I setted Texture Coordinates to UV but it doesn't work as intended. I managed to make it work with Node Texture, but the assignment is to do it with Displace Modifier.

Thank you

[image: pot to displace]
[image: displacement map]

Comment: It could be possible that you don't have enough mesh faces to displace them with a fine enough resolution. In that case, try adding a subdivision modifier (e.g. set to 3 subdivisions) beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you want to unwrap your pot, which you said you already have.
Next you want to make sure that you either have sufficient subdivisions or add a subd modifier at the top of the stack so the displacement modifier has enough geo to actually displace.

Add the displace modifier, go to the Texture Properties tab and select Image or Movie as the Type and load the image you posted.

[image: Texture Properties Tab]

Back on the modifier tab, set the Texture Coordinates to UV, the UV Map to the map you made above and adjust the strength as you see fit.

[image: Modifier Tab]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! i was missing the understanding of the subdivision layer. Noi it works perfectly. thank you