# Indent an object using an image

Tags: modeling

I want to make a custom dice set with the theme Darksiders

[image]

This is the image I would like to be on the d20 dice on the 20 side. however I do not know how to put the mark into the d20 Model.

I know how to put in numbers into the dice and I tried to make a dent in it with a smaller simple cube and it worked fine but not when I try with this Darksider mark. i even tried a more simpler version of the image but not even that worked. the result was either nothing, or a wierd and inconsistent texture into the dice model

I would be really happy if someone could help me with this.

thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean you want to mark one of the faces with this symbol?

Comment: Hello :). What is the technique you tried and didn't work for you? Do you want to use the image as a Bump texture, or actual indented geometry?

Comment: i tried to use boolean to indent geometry. similar method when i put the numbers into the dice. make sure its a mesh object, then go to the dice model, add the boolean modifier. 
but it didnt work for this one @JachymMichal

Comment: and im not sure what u mean with mark, i want it to be an acual mark on the dice when i print it with a 3D printer. if that makes sence? @FrederikSteinmetz

Comment: The best way would be probably to Import the [logo as an .svg](https://www.deviantart.com/derant/art/Darksiders-II-loading-logo-322291497) and then manually (or using Boolean) cut the relief into the dice

Comment: Related: [How can I convert an SVG to a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/136/78972)

Comment: how do i do it manually since it doesnt work automatically?
@JachymMichal

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the DISPLACE modifier on the plane you want the SHAPE of the image.
You'll mesh will need a lot of geometry to be able to show the shape of your image.

[image]

For a detailed explanation on the setup read:
[Displace Modifier on an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165711/displace-modifier-on-an-object)

Comment: i looked up how to use it and either im doing it wrong or it doesnt work @Sanbaldo

Comment: share your test so we can check what's wrong

Comment: https://sta.sh/01f1n33l0hv7
https://sta.sh/0omrlbqeihh

here is the result of me trying to copy what i see in the picture that you sent. honestly i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: you need to increase the level of subdivision in the subdivision modifier (viewport). you'll need at least 5. then you need to swith to "simple model" instead of "catmull"